# 80s or 90s teen fiction romance/horror, takes place in Scotland

Tags: story-identification, horror

I read this book once when I was young and fell in love with it, but my mother took it away and I never saw it again. I can't find anything online no matter what I search. What I remember is:

- the cover had a couple people on the bank of a lake in the distance, and the foreground was a hand sticking out of the water.
- a girl goes to stay with family in Scotland, and in the room where she's sleeping, she gets woken up by the pictures hung above the bed glowing.
- the male love interest has a Porsche, which she crashes trying to learn left handed driving
- the guy's sister ends up being found floating face down in a fountain (or a pond, a body of water on the property)
- there's a rock with a red stain on it, which I think was from a blood stained kiss from some other part in the storyline
- parts of it were pretty creepy.

Please, please, if anybody has any idea which book this is, let me know. I've been searching for about five years now.

Comment: '... trying to learn left-handed driving': this suggests she could drive right-handed, so she learned to drive in another country. Where was she from?

Comment: mmmh...this sounds sort of familiar, I think...I'll see if I can find something.

Comment: I believe she is from the usa, but I'm not positive. Thanks a-user, please let me know if you find anything!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

*[Deadly Sleep](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3672506-deadly-sleep)* is the book, I believe.  I've been searching for the answer too.  I read it for a book report in middle school in the eighties.

> Jaynie visits her friend Evelyn in Scotland to take a break from her problems at home, including a painful break-up with her boyfriend. Just as she begins to relax, she starts hearing eerie voices in the night, and when she investigates, she sees a ghastly figure rising from the slime of the lake.

This is the first book of the *Twilight: Where Darkness Begins* series.

Comment: OMG!! Thats it!! Thank you so much <3 I can finally rest now.

Answer (score 3):

I checked a lot of "young-adult" books within the romance/paranormal genre, published between the late '80s / early '90s, and I tried to match your description. Actually, there is no book that matches perfectly...but I found this one whose story and overall feeling sound very similar to yours:

["The Accident", by Diane Hoh, 1991](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0590551248)

Two reviews (sort of):

[Review 1](http://rsvpordie.blogspot.it/2008/11/accident-diane-hoh.html)

[Review 2](http://yarevisited.blogspot.it/2010/07/point-horror-accident-diane-hoh.html)

Is this the one you're looking for?

Comment: Ive actually come across that one as well, but its not the one. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: the point is, if it's a book that was sort of popular at the time, then it has to be mentioned somewhere. Googling here and there, I found plenty of lists about young-adult books within that particular genre, I think they were (they still are, probably) quite widespread in the early '90s. But I just couldn't find something that matched perfectly. I could try and search for it again this weekend, maybe I missed it yesterday. I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: Yeah,  I was thinking about the popularity and it must not have been a huge seller. I've been searching for literally five years so this is kind of my last resort, in the slim chance that maybe someone has read it and enjoyed it as much as I did.  Thanks for your help, I do have my doubts that Google holds any answers, but hopefully you may find something I've missed :)